# Is there a way to decrease the size of the main.chunk.js created by create-react-app? or to separeate it into various smaller ones?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

We are using create-react-app in out company.

When i create an anailis of the build with `cra-bundle-analyzer` it shows this image:
[bundle analisys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAO0K.png)

I want to know how the main.chunk.js chunk is created, it seems to have all the contents of the src folder.

we have code splitted routes, so if a user goes to the changeService route, it loads the chunk for that file. But as you can see at pageload, the changeService folder is on the main.chunk.js even though the changeService is not loaded on the homepage.

I want to know if there is a way to remove this code from the main.chunk.js, and just download it when it's needed, as I said, if I go to the route of the changeService, it loads the chunk for the changeService, but in the main.chunk.js it seems to load everything in src...

Is there a way to make main.chunk.js smaller? Just the stuff I need in the homepage? and not stuff i dont like the changeService folder or others?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: it doesnt say nothing about the main.chunk.js as I said i have code splitting on my routes.

Comment: @yolomartini did u find any solution?